# Does Angular DI work at both Module and Controller level?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, dependency-injection

There are plenty of examples describing how DI operates at controller level in Angular.js but I am new to Angular and I am looking at the code of creating a new module and when I look at following code:

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

When it says that if this module is using other modules then we can specify them in in []. Is is also not a kind of Dependency injection?

So would it be correct statement to say that DI works at both Module and Controller level in Angular.JS?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, DI works at both Module and Controller level.

But, the difference is

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);
```

in the above line you inject `modules` that `myApp` module depends upon.

Whereas, at controller level, you inject `services`.

```
var app = angular.module("myApp", ['navigation']); 
app.controller("appController", function(navDataService){
});
```

So, when AngularJS bootstrap application, it look at `module` dependencies and load those modules and make the `services` available, so that, they can be injected into contoller.